# Python code for Points2One in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I am trying to automate a process where I am converting point shapefiles to polygons in QGIS using Points2One. I am fairly new to Python coding and have not been able to find any example code online of this being done.

Is it possible to do this using Python code?

I am using QGIS version 2.14.

Comment: Have you looked into the code of Points2One? http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~goyodiaz/points2one/trunk/files/head:/points2one/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about points2one, but one option would be to first convert points to line layer:

[How to connect points by lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137585/how-to-connect-points-by-lines)

Then you may use the python code/logic in the polygonizer plug-in noted in the question to convert line to polygon layer:

[Create polygon layer from polyline layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30765/create-polygon-layer-from-polyline-layer)