# Create network from GPS coordinates QGIS

Tags: coordinates, gps, connection, path

I'm trying to map all the recent flights that a friend has taken. I have GPS coordinates in excel that I've converted into a .CSV file and imported into QGIS. I now have one layer of origin airport data sets, and one with destination airports. How do I get QGIS to connect them into individual paths?
I can't seem to remember how I did it the first time...

[image: Flight paths]

Comment: This answer may be helpful for you. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/137592/181131